# Uppercasing in AvalonEdit

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonedit

I am writing a movie script editor using AvalonEdit.

I extended the DocumentLine class to have a "Type" property, with the value representing either a "Character", "Dialog Line", etc.

I would like document lines of a certain type within the script to be written in upper case (character names for example).

Is there an extension point within the rendering pipeline that would allow me to fetch a document line and change it's casing ?

I tried creating a class that extends DocumentColorizingTransformer, but changing the casing within the "protected override void ColorizeLine(DocumentLine line)" method didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is difficult, because upper-casing can change the mapping between displayed characters and the document (visual columns vs. document offsets).

For example, the single character 'ß' (German sharp s) exists only as a lower-case letter, and gets converted to the two-character string "SS" when calling `string.ToUpper()`.
Editing this text is tricky: we can't allow the user to replace only one of the 'S', as the underlying document only contains the 'ß'.

A simple solution is to use the `char.ToUpper()` method instead, enforcing a one-to-one mapping between original and uppercase characters. This will keep letters like 'ß' unchanged.

In AvalonEdit 4.2, only two transformations are allowed on the already generated VisualLineElements:

- Change the text run properties, e.g. font size, text color, etc.
- Split a VisualLineElement in two - this is used internally by `ChangeLinePart()` so that properties can be changed for a text portion.

This means it is not possible to do a text replacement in a colorizer, you need to implement this using a `VisualLineElementGenerator`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Makes all text after a colon (until the end of line) upper-case.
/// </summary>
public class UppercaseGenerator : VisualLineElementGenerator
{
    public override int GetFirstInterestedOffset(int startOffset)
    {
        TextDocument document = CurrentContext.Document;
        int endOffset = CurrentContext.VisualLine.LastDocumentLine.EndOffset;
        for (int i = startOffset; i < endOffset; i++) {
            char c = document.GetCharAt(i);
            if (c == ':')
                return i + 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public override VisualLineElement ConstructElement(int offset)
    {
        DocumentLine line = CurrentContext.Document.GetLineByOffset(offset);
        return new UppercaseText(CurrentContext.VisualLine, line.EndOffset - offset);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Displays a portion of the document text, but upper-cased.
    /// </summary>
    class UppercaseText : VisualLineText
    {
        public UppercaseText(VisualLine parentVisualLine, int length) : base(parentVisualLine, length)
        {
        }

        protected override VisualLineText CreateInstance(int length)
        {
            return new UppercaseText(ParentVisualLine, length);
        }

        public override TextRun CreateTextRun(int startVisualColumn, ITextRunConstructionContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

            int relativeOffset = startVisualColumn - VisualColumn;
            StringSegment text = context.GetText(context.VisualLine.FirstDocumentLine.Offset + RelativeTextOffset + relativeOffset, DocumentLength - relativeOffset);
            char[] uppercase = new char[text.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Count; i++) {
                uppercase[i] = char.ToUpper(text.Text[text.Offset + i]);
            }
            return new TextCharacters(uppercase, 0, uppercase.Length, this.TextRunProperties);
        }
    }
}
```

In AvalonEdit 4.3.0.8868, I added the method `VisualLine.ReplaceElement()`. This can be used to replace the default `VisualText` elements with `UppercaseText` elements within a line transformer (colorizer).

Note that it is also possible to implement support for 'ß' being displayed as 'SS'. For that, you would have to implement your own copy of `VisualLineText` instead of just overriding the existing one. Then you can use a visual length that differs from the document length. The `GetRelativeOffset` and `GetVisualColumns` methods would be used to provide the mapping between the document and visual coordinates.

---

There is another option you could use: small caps.

```
// in the colorizer:
ChangeLinePart(start, end, e => e.TextRunProperties.SetTypographyProperties(new CapsTypography()));

// helper class
class CapsTypography : DefaultTextRunTypographyProperties
{
    public override FontCapitals Capitals {
        get { return FontCapitals.SmallCaps; }
    }
}
```

However, WPF will render small caps only when using an OpenType font that supports them. In my testing, `Cambria` worked with small caps, most other fonts don't.
Also, the `SetTypographyProperties` method and `DefaultTextRunTypographyProperties` class require AvalonEdit 4.3.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer, I really appreciate it. You're always really helpful. :)